Google Refresh token
Flutter
Solution for getting refresh tokens after logging in with Google.
Currently, there is no refreshToken returned so not able to fetch refreshToken and generate new accessToken.
A new access token is generated only if the user logs out or logs in again with Google which is not convenient for the user.
expecting refresh token

To get a refresh token from the google_sign_in package, you should first mention it when calling GoogleSignIn:
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
        forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
        scopes: [
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        ],
      );

After that, signin:
    GoogleSignInAccount? account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication auth = await account.authentication;

then take the serverauthcode
    String? serverAuthCode = account.serverAuthCode;

After getting the serverauthcode call this function with the code as the parameter.
Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> _exchangeCodeForTokens(String code) async
{
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: {
          'code': code,
          'client_id': 'your client id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
          'client_secret': 'your client secret',
          'redirect_uri': '',
          'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return jsonDecode(response.body);
    }
    else {
        log("Error: ${response.body}");
        return null;
    }
}

Hope this answer helps.
